# Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List<Account>

Tags: class, limits

Even it is pretty easy one, but error is not able to solve by me.

```
public class one{
    public List<Account> accs{set;get;}

    public void main(){
        accs = [select id,name,type from account];
        for(Account acc : accs){
             acc.id= accs.id; // Error 
        }
    }
}
```

even i have used for loop to come out from error. but i didn't.

please help me for this problem...!

Thanking you

KS Kumaar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `acc`

```
 public void main(){
            accs = [select id,name,type from account];
            for(Account acc : accs){
                 acc.id= acc.id; // Error //remove s use acc
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi Tushar Sharma, acc.id= acc.id ==> Which means assigning it self?

Comment: @KSKumaar yes, What you are trying to do here?

Comment: Yeah.... Tushar Sharma. I got the mistake what i gave made.
Thank you Tushar Sharma for your help